# How do I get the input to cut off or wrap around at a certain point?

Tags: c, text, console, cmd

Alrighty, so after a day and a bit of being on stackoverflow, I learned it's useful being on this site :) I ended up getting my program to work. I can get an unlimited amount of text files in on the command line and display them as well! So it looks like this:

---

CMD Console

c:\Users\Username\Desktop> wrapfile.exe hello.txt how.txt. are.txt you.txt random.txt

Hello How are you doing today? I hope you're doing quite well. This is just a test to see how much I can fit on the screen.

---

Now, I wana build on this program. How would I get this new found text to wrap around? Like, if you wanted to make it that, every 40 characters or so, the text jumps to the next line... how could we go about doing something like that?

Thanks again!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int l = 1;
        while(l != argc)
{
        FILE *fp; // declaring variable


        fp = fopen(argv[l], "rb");
        l++;


    if (fp != NULL) // checks the return value from fopen
    {
        int i = 1;
        do
        {
            i = fgetc(fp);     // scans the file 
            printf("%c",i);
            printf(" ");
        }
        while(i!=-1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like you just want to print a newline every 40 characters.

Comment: My suggestion, implement a character counter, and just reset it every 40 chars and then insert a newline.

Comment: Well, I was thinking of trying to put the text files into a string, and then scanning the string and every 40 characters, add a \n. It probably sounds barbaric lol, but I'm new to C and I'm just trying to learn some new methods before school starts next September :p

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here we go...this looks a little different to yours, but this is ISO/ANSI C 1989 standard.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     FILE *fd = NULL;
     char linebuf[40];
     int arg = 1;

     while (arg < argc) {
         fd = fopen(argv[arg], "r");
         if (NULL != fd) {
              /* fgets(char *buf, size_t buflen, FILE *fd): returns NULL on error. */
              while (NULL != fgets(linebuf, sizeof(linebuf), fd)) {
                  printf("%s\n", linebuf);
              }
              fclose(fd);
         } else {
              fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open \"%s\"\n", argv[arg]);
         }
         ++arg;
     }
 }
```