# How to have text jump to the next line in a command window? C programming?

Tags: c, string, text, cmd, argv

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get the input to cut off or wrap around at a certain point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13755035/how-do-i-get-the-input-to-cut-off-or-wrap-around-at-a-certain-point)

Alrighty, so after a day and a bit of being on stackoverflow, I learned it's useful being on this site :) I ended up getting my program to work. I can get an unlimited amount of text files in on the command line and display them as well! So it looks like this

---

I have:

CMD Console

c:\Users\Username\Desktop> wrapfile.exe hello.txt how.txt. are.txt you.txt random.txt

Hello How are you doing today? I hope you're doing quite well. This is just a test to see how much I can fit on the screen.

---

I need:

CMD Console

c:\Users\Username\Desktop> wrapfile.exe hello.txt how.txt. are.txt you.txt random.txt

Hello How are you doing today?
I hope you're doing quite well.
This is just a test to see how
much I can fit on the screen.

---

Now, I wana build on this program. How would I get this new found text to wrap around? Like, if you wanted to make it that, every 40 characters or so, the text jumps to the next line... how could we go about doing something like that?

Thanks again!

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int l = 1;
        while(l != argc)
{
        FILE *fp; // declaring variable


        fp = fopen(argv[l], "rb");
        l++;


    if (fp != NULL) // checks the return value from fopen
    {
        int i = 1;
        do
        {
            i = fgetc(fp);     // scans the file 
            printf("%c",i);
            printf(" ");
        }
        while(i!=-1);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error.\n");
    }
}


}
```

Comment: Count chars and insert '\n' or '\r\n' (depending on the OS/console) on your own? (that's pretty much how it's done unless your console/window is set to X chars wide)

Comment: I actually was in the process of editing my question lol, let me know if what I changed helped you understand it better. I added the "What I need" section below the CMD window example.

Comment: I'm sorry but i don't see any difference in the output... (Fixed the output to convey what you meant) and i still stand by me previous comment.

Comment: Yeah, I read it over and realized. Ironically, my formatting question was formatted incorrectly lol. It should be better now :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to word-wrap your file?

IF that's the case, here's a high level sequence of steps that I would do

- First, I'd load the file into a character array
- Second, I'd generate a new file.  I would print 40 characters to the new file, and then the `\n` char.
- Depending on your requirement, you may or may not want to replace the old file with the new file.

if you just need to print word-wrapped text to the console, instead of step 2, you can just print 40 chars to the command line and then a `\n`, and repeat for the next 40

Comment: You don't need the new file. When printing just add a line-break it the "chars width" you need.

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm going to want to keep everything in the same file. I just need it displayed differently in the command window.

Comment: @JamesHeartly then you have to over-write the file with a new one.  files on disk typically don't support random-access inserts

Comment: Alright, but will the text still appear on the console window? And I had another idea on how to solve it... if I used malloc to find out how many bytes the text file is, couldn't I just select 40 bytes / 80 bytes to display (1 byte = 1 word) and display the remaining 40 on the next line? Is that possible or am I walking into a land of non-existent magic?

Comment: @JamesHeartly if you don't need a word-wrapped file, you don't need to generate the second file at all.  you just have to print 40 chars at at time to the console

Comment: Exactly! That is exactly what I want lol, but the question is... how? My friend is working on something similar, but his code seems long and complex and I honestly think he did more work then he had to. He keeps telling me I'm under thinking it, but I believe he's over thinking it, I wana know a short way of doing exactly what you just say :D