# Fahrenheit to Celsius program improvement and choosing the output

Tags: c, converters, temperature

I just started programming in C a few days ago and I want to improve my program but not sure how to do it.

This program is a Fahrenheit to Celsius and vice versa converter. I did it in the simplest way possible. But now I want to do it so that I have 2 functions c2f and f2c which take the temperature as a parameter and when I run the program I want do choose whether I want to covert from F to C or from C to F (something like TempConverter -f 32 this should only convert 32 into celsius and TempConverter -c 100 should covert 100 into Fahrenheit).

I think my functions should be something like this : **float c2f (float c)** and **float f2c (float f)**

But how exactly do it do it so when I run something like **> TempConverter -f 50.0** I get something like this let's say?
**10.00°C = 50.00°F**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Local Declarations
    float Celsius, Fahrenheit, Fahrenheit_1, Celsius_2;

    // Statements
    printf("Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: ");
    scanf("%f", &Fahrenheit);
    printf("Fahrenheit temperature is: %5.1f F\n\a", Fahrenheit);

    Celsius = (100.0 / 180.0) * (Fahrenheit - 32);

    printf("Celsius temperature is: %8.1f C\n\n\a", Celsius);

    printf("Enter the temperature in Celsius: ");
    scanf("%f", &Celsius_2);
    printf("Celsius temperature is: %8.1f C\n\a", Celsius_2);

    Fahrenheit_1 = 32 + (Celsius_2 * (180.0 / 100.0));

    printf("Fahrenheit temperature is: %5.1f F\a", Fahrenheit_1);

    return 0;

}
```

**Current output:**

*Enter the temperature in Fahrenheit: 20

Fahrenheit temperature is:  20.0 F

Celsius temperature is:     -6.7 C

Enter the temperature in Celsius: 40

Celsius temperature is:     40.0 C

Fahrenheit temperature is: 104.0 F*

**Desired Output**

> TempConverter -f 50.0

10.00°C = 50.00°F

Comment: If you want to respond to command line switches, you need to add argc and argv to your main. And go through argv and figure out what functions to call.

Comment: float c2f (float c) { return 32 + (c * (180.0 / 100.0)); } etc

Comment: There are several posts regarding the processing of command line arguments. For example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13766985/how-can-i-process-command-line-arguments-in-c

Comment: First step is to define your main function as `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Then you can retrieve the arguments passed to the program in `argv`

Comment: Minor: Change "%.1f" to "%.2f" to get 2 digits to the right of ".".

Comment: Relax, you'll get to that later in the book (assuming you're reading K&R).

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you'll need to do is add command line arguments to your code, like so:

```
int main( int argc, char **argv )
```

`argc` contains the number of parameters entered on the command line; it is always >= 1.

`argv` contains pointers to each of the command line argument strings.  `argv[0]` always points to the string you used to start the program.  `argv[argc]` is always NULL.

So, if you called your program as

```
TempConverter -f 50.00
```

then

```
argc == 3
argv[0] == "TempConverter"
argv[1] == "-f"
argv[2] == "50.00"
argv[3] == NULL
```

Note that to use the last parameter in your conversion functions, you'll need to convert it from a string to a floating-point value.  `strtod` is the library function of choice for this:

```
char *check;
double intemp = strtod(argv[2], &check);
```

After the conversion, `check` will point to the first character in the string that was *not* converted to a floating point value.  If this character is something other than whitespace or 0, then the input value was not a valid floating-point string.

So, the general order of operations:

1. Check the value of `argc`.  For your purposes, it needs to be 3.
2. Convert `argv[2]` to a floating-point value using `strtod`. Make sure the check character is either 0 or whitespace.
3. Check your fahrenheit/celcius switch; it needs to be either `"-f"` or `"-c"` (or whatever you decide on).
4. Call the appropriate conversion function based on the fahrenheit/celcius switch, and display the result.

Comment: Hey John, I believe sscanf would be a better way to convert a string into a floating point number, wouldn't it? Although I am not entirely sure how to use it properly.

Comment: No.  Imagine you fat-finger a string like `3.1r159`.  `sscanf` will convert and assign the `"3.1"` portion and return 1 to indicate a successful conversion, leaving the rest in the input stream to foul up the next read.  `strtod` will allow you to catch the error and reject the input completely.

Comment: Gah, I was thinking of `scanf`, not `sscanf`; you won't have leftover crap in the input stream.  But the main point still stands - `sscanf` will indicate success for what *should* be bad input.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use commandline arguments that come as arguments to `main`

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Here `argc` corresponds to the number of arguments supplied and the arguments are stored in `argv`. Note that the name of the program is also considered an argument and is stored in `argv[0]`. Assuming you expect a flag `-f` or `-c` followed by a `float`, you can use them inside `main` as follows:

```
/** 
 * Check for the expected number of arguments (3)
 * (0) program name
 * (1) flag
 * (2) temperature
 */
if (argc!=3)
    printf("Incorrect number of arguments");

if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-f"))
   // process from fahrenheit to celsius
else if (!strcmp(argv[1], "-c"))
   // process from celsius to fahrenheit
else
   printf("Invalid flag\n");
```

Note, whenever you are dealing with user input, it is very important to **check** that the input corresponds to what you expect. My suggested code gives some example, but you should think hard about how you can make it even more secure

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pankrates! Just a question: why do we have a "!" before the strcmp? Why are we negating it?

Comment: The function `strcmp` returns `0` on a successful match

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

main(int argc,char** argv)
{
         int result;

         printf("\nValue of Celcius: \n");
         scanf("%i", &argc);
         printf("\n%i Celcius = ", argc);

         result = ((argc * 9) /5) + 32;

         printf("%i Fahrenheit\n", result);

         getchar();
         getchar();
         return 0;

}
```