# C - Easy program NO/WRONG output

Tags: c, converters, output

This is my 1st post here @Stackoverflow

This is my program, when I give it the following input: **TemperatureConverter ->f 50** it should output: **50.00°F = 10.00°C**. Instead it doesn't output anything.

I spent over 30min trying to debug it but couldn't find anything?

Any thoughts?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float c2f(float);
float f2c(float);

float Fahrenheit,Celsius;
```

Comment: I just stared programming in C 4 days ago. I have no idea what debugger to use, since I don't know any C debuggers. So yeah, I pretty much started at the code :)

Comment: [Made a new account?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19414063/c-fahrenheit-to-celsius-program-improvements-choosing-the-output/19414196#19414196)

Comment: Nope, this is my 1st account here. Why?

Comment: Since the code you are showing, is literally the code written by me in response to another account less than an hour ago

Comment: Oh, well a friend sent me the code on FaceBook. We're working on the same program and apparently his compiled while mine didn't. Anyway, his code didn't output anything so he sent it to me to find the error and I couldn't. So i posted it here to StackOverflow.

Comment: So maybe we posted his code to S.O as well idk. What's the account's username btw?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `->c` and `->f` as command line parameters is going to end in tears.  `>` is almost always a special shell character used to redirect output to a file.  Your program will never see that character, unless you invoke the program like:

```
TemperatureConverter -\>f 50
```

or

```
TemperatureConverter '->f' 50
```

or

```
TemperatureConverter "->f" 50
```

Also, your program will only give the output you're looking for if you use `->c`, not `->f`:

```
TemperatureConverter '->c' 50
```

Your program does work fine, by the way - it's just that it's never getting the input you expect.

Comment: The reason your program isn't displaying _anything_ is, as Carl points out, that you've got that `>` character there... Effectively, when you type `TemperatureConverter ->f 50`, you're executing the command `TemperatureConverter - 50` and redirecting the output to a file named `f`. So the expected output ("Incorrect number of arguments") is being written to the file named `f` instead of being displayed on your screen.